# Type an untyped package with types from another package

Tags: typescript-typings

Is it possible to re-export an existing typed module and use its types for an untyped module?

I am importing a library `react-final-form-html5-validation` that is just a tiny wrapper around typed `react-final-form`.

Are there any options for this?

I have tried many many many things ......., but this looks most promising, however, `react-final-form` does not declare a namespace and so I cannot use its types like I can use the `React` below.

`project/index.d.ts`

```
/// <reference types="react-final-form" />
//// <reference types="./node_modules/react-final-form/dist/index.d.ts" />
//// <reference path="./node_modules/react-final-form/dist/index.d.ts" />
//// <amd-dependency path="./node_modules/react-final-form/dist/index.d.ts" />
// importing resolves the types, but also turns it into a module, which in turn breaks it
// import * as RFF from react-final-form; 
// import { FieldProps } from react-final-form;
// export * from react-final-form;

declare module 'react-final-form-html5-validation' {
  var Field: React.ComponentType<FieldProps>
}
```

`project/src/index.tsx`

```
import { Field, Abc } from 'react-final-form-html5-validation'
// correct: Module '"react-final-form-html5-validation"' has no exported member 'Abc'

// later in App.render() { return ( .....
      <Field />

// Field is of type React.ComponentType<any>
```

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into the same problem, and I'm not very experienced in typescript so I'm not sure if this is the correct method of handling this very well, but I think I have a solution that seems to be working.

I implemented the types to match the ones from flow that were provided in the `react-final-form-html5-validation` files, which was basically FieldProps, but with some extra props to account for the error messages. I've only tested a little bit, but it seems to be working at the minute. As I said though, I'm fairly new to typescript and have only a basic understanding.

```
declare module 'react-final-form-html5-validation' {
    import { ComponentType } from 'react';
    import { FieldProps } from 'react-final-form';
    type Messages = {
        badInput?: string;
        patternMismatch?: string;
        rangeOverflow?: string;
        rangeUnderflow?: string;
        stepMismatch?: string;
        tooLong?: string;
        tooShort?: string;
        typeMismatch?: string;
        valueMissing?: string;
    };
    export type Html5ValidationFieldProps = FieldProps<any> & Messages;
    export const Field: ComponentType<Html5ValidationFieldProps>;
}
```

The `<FieldProps<any>` part was taken from the main `react-final-form` which seems to be how the Field element is exported from there too.

Comment: Where do you put this content? When I write it to top-level index.tsx file, it says `Invalid module name in augmentation. Module 'react-final-form-html5-validation' resolves to an untyped module`

Comment: @Qwerty Oh sorry, I have a `globals.d.ts` file which is where I put anything related to modules that don't have full typescript support. I'm using `create-react-app`, with their out of the box typescript support, so I'm not sure if there's something in the config for typescript that ensures it picks up definitions like this.